# Is an oscillation the same as a period?

Tags: oscillators

Is one oscillation from peak to trough to peak again or is it just peak to trough? Doing a homework question and want to be sure I have the right definition

Comment: In more general usage a "period" is a property of an oscillation (others are ampliture, timbre (relative sizes of superposition weights in a Fourier expansion) and epoch or phase). The usage you show is not precise and the question needs tightening up. My *guess* is that it would likely refer to the full period - that's how I would read it - but if you interpreted as the half period (peak to trough), then you could not be faulted as clearly to use "oscillation" in this way is not precise.

Comment: "One oscillation" of a smoothly periodic waveform would be one full cycle, starting at any point (peak, trough, uphill zero crossing, downhill zero crossing, or anywhere in-between) and ending at the next equivalent point.  The distance between these points (the "length" of the oscillation) is the "period".

Comment: Someone who uses "oscillation" in a homework question when they mean "period" or "complete cycle" is not doing their students a favor. Even if it might be deduced that they are intended to be equivalent. Precise language is the hallmark of clarity in thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is one oscillation from peak to trough to peak again or is it just peak to trough?**

This is a definition issue.

An internet search through some of the free dictionaries out there gives ([link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oscillation)):

> *Physics.*
>   **a.**  an effect expressible as a quantity that repeatedly and regularly fluctuates above and below some mean value, as the pressure of a sound wave or the voltage of an alternating current.
>   **b.** a single fluctuation between maximum and minimum values in such an effect.

And ([link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oscillation)):

> *1. (General Physics) physics statistics*
>   **a.** regular fluctuation in value, position, or state about a mean value, such as the variation in an alternating current or the regular swinging of a pendulum.
>   **b.** a single cycle of such a fluctuation

It has two meanings in physics: "an oscillation" can mean the very act that something is "swinging" in general. But about the other meaning, it seems the two sources do not entirely agree if "an oscillation" is `between maximum and minimum` or if it is `a single cycle` (that is, from maximum to maximum).

We are close to the answer, but a proper place for such a question would rather be https://english.stackexchange.com/

---

> **Is an oscillation the same as a period?**

Your title is another question. And the answer is no.

The word "period" means something very specific, and is *not* the same thing as an oscillation in either meaning. A "period" is not the act of swinging, but the *time* for a complete cycle of the oscillation (from maximum to maximum). Usually denoted $T$ with units of *seconds* (or *seconds per cycle* if you like).

Answer (score 1):

Honoring the complex alternatives, here is a simple one: I would say, oscillation means a period of a periodical system in time.