# Difference between "Periodic motion" and "Oscillating Motion"

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, terminology, oscillators

So far I know one of them is a special case of the other: The Oscillating motion being the special case of Periodic motion. But I don't know the precise "Kinematical definition" of each one. I mean when you have an "Equation of motion" for a particle, how will you determine it's either a "Periodic motion" or an "Oscillating motion"? If some periodic functions appear in an equation of motion, can we call it a "Periodic motion"? If so how can we recognize it from "Oscillating motion"?

Comment: A periodic function $f(t)$ is any one where $f(t) = f(t+T)$ for some $T$. An oscillating function is more vague, but it tends to mean a specific type of periodic function, including the ones that look like sinusoids.

Comment: What @knzhou said is the main difference.  Plus we don't normally use the word *oscillation* in a system of more than one dimension, while *periodic* is used in all dimensions.

Comment: @knzhou So far the definition of a periodic motion seemed to be tied to the definition of a periodic function. but still it would be much better if you gave a more precise definition of oscillating motion

Comment: @garyp Could we say oscillating motion is just periodic motion but just in one dimension?

Comment: Partially.   Oscillation has an implication of a regular back-and-forth.   Periodic can mean any kind of repeating pattern.  I could have pauses, jerks, reversals, etc, as long as the pattern repeats.  But we don't tend to use *oscillation* in more than one dimension.

Comment: From [Oscillation] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation) it seems that an Oscillation does not need to be periodic, a good example being provided by the heart:slow when you are cool, fast when you are facing a danger (ans some other situations).

Comment: @claudechuber I don't think so. Think of a simple harmonic oscillator. It's periodic. What are you referring to as I think is actually "Fluctuation" not "Oscillation"

Comment: I'm just referring to a wikipedia article which usually makes sense. I don't understand what you mean by "I don't think so". You are telling that a simple harmonic oscillator is periodic, which is correct, and I didn't say the contrary. I hope you understand that "Does not need to be" does not mean "Is not".

Comment: @claudechuber Yes. But usually textbooks define an oscillating motion a back-and-forth periodic motion. Besides Not everything in wikipedia bound to be correct.

Comment: I would say that a periodic function has far more structure to it than an oscillating function; oscillating functions are a subset of periodic functions. An almost periodic function is an oscillating function also. Polynomials could be considered oscillating in some sense also if they cut the axis often.

Comment: @ArthurSuvorov 1.What specific structures a periodic function can have than an oscillating function? Can you describe it comprehensively in an answer? 2. What do you mean by "...if they cut the axis often."?

Comment: Slightly related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173854/is-an-oscillation-the-same-as-a-period/173863

Answer (score 3):

In what follows I will only talk about the motion in one spacial dimension. Let me use the following definitions.

1. Periodic motion - the one in which all the processes repeat after the period $T$.
2. Oscillating motion - the one in which we have turning points.

Clearly, the second is a subclass of the first. Now let me explain in the language of the potentials. Again, in (classical!) mechanics we only have two options:

a) Motion in a bounded periodic potential with the energy above the absolute maximum, e.g. $V(x) = \sin(x)$ with $E>1$.

b)  Motion with turning points. There are two possibilities when this can happen, but they are indistinguishable in (classical!) mechanics.

Namely:

b1) Motion in a potential which has an absolute maximum, with the energy below this maximum (it's also useful to require for the energy not to coincide with any of the maxima in order to avoid infinite periods). Example: $V(x)=\sin (x)$ with $-1<E<1$

b2) Motion in potential of type $V(x)\to\infty$ as $|x|\to \infty$ with an arbitrary high energy. Exmaple: $V(x) = x^{2n}$, $E>0$.

Using our classification, we can say that both a) and b) cases belong to the $1$ class, while it is only $b$ that belongs to $2$.

OK, you may wonder now if these two cases are physically different. Of course, they are. It can be best understood when one thinks of such quantities as momentum or the (abbreviated) action.

Let's introduce the following definitions. Under the assumption that the system is closed, we can write its Hamiltonian as

$$H = \dfrac{p^2}{2m} + V(x) = E$$

where $E$ is the value of the Hamiltonian function - the energy of the system. Since the energy is conserved, we can solve the equation above for the momentum:

$$p(x) = \sqrt{2 m (E - V(x))}$$

In the case b), two interesting things happen to the momentum at the turning points: 1) It vanishes 2) It changes the sign. Neither of those happen in the case a).

Now let's talk about the classical abbreviated action, defined as the integral of the momentum over the period:

$$S = \int_{\mathcal{C}} p(x) \operatorname{d}x$$

The contour $\mathcal{C}$ denotes the part of the $x$-axis between the turning points, traveled there and back. The integral is nonzero dues to the fact that the momentum has changed its sign. If you are familiar with the complex analysis, this can be formulated in a slightly different way. We can complexify the position $x$ and consider the integral above as an integral along the closed contour in the complex $x$-plane. This integral is nonzero due to the presence of the singularity inside it. This singularity is the branch cut of the momentum - it does not let you to shrink the contour.

[image: The Riemannian surface of the harmonic oscillator]

A good way of thinking about the motion in the periodic potential above the absolute maximum is thinking of the motion of the circle. It helps to imagine a finite interval of space, and a particle which by the end of the period $T$ goes from one to another end of it.

Now, you can ask yourself what is the Riemannian surface of the momentum in this case, and why is the integral nonzero - indeed, we have no singularities! In this case it is the topology who is responsible for the fact that the integration contour cannot be shrunk. Namely, the Riemannian surface is now either an infinite strip in the complex plane, or a parallelogram (depending on the analytic properties of the potential).

These ideas have very deep and interesting consequences:

1. Studying the global properties of the Riemannian surfaces allows to calculate certain things in a very cute and beautiful way (like calculating the classical action via employing the Picard-Fuchs equation for the Riemannian surface of the momentum)
2. It turns out that exactly same ideas can be applied to the corresponding quantum-mechanical problems due to the fact that the quantum analogue of the momentum lives on the same Riemannian surface.

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive and detailed answer. But still I'm somehow confused. 1.First you said: "I will only talk about the motion in one spacial dimension". I know that periodic motion can be in more than one dimension. But does it mean that we can have an oscillation(a periodic motion with turning points) in more than one dimension too 2. After defining Periodic and Oscillating Motions you said: "Clearly, the second is a subclass of the first" but the case b2 where the motion is unbounded seems not periodic.

Comment: Sorry, they was I used the word 'bounded' was not very accurate (I made corrections to the post). The difference between b1) and b2) is that in b1) the potential is bounded (it has an absolute maximum), while in b2) the potential goes to infinity on both sides. However, the motion is bounded in both cases - in classical mechanics the particle doesn't know anything about the shape of potential beyond its turning points. While in the case a) the motion is unbounded - the particle never stops.

Comment: Speaking of generalisation to higher dimensions. It's pretty much the same. a) The unbounded periodic motion can be realised in a periodic potential like [this one](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/frac8c/x4.png). b) Bounded periodic motion can occur in potentials like [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/Paraboloid_700.gif). In order to study it, people typically switch to the angular and radial coordinates. Then, the motion along the radial coordinate will be analogous to the case b) in one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

From a physical stand point they are very similar. When we consider the orbit of a planet around a star, we consider its period. Hence, orbits are periodic in nature. We don't refer to the oscillations of the planet.

In contrast, say we have a spring with a mass attached, and set it out of equilibrium. We don't typically talk about the periodic nature of the system, but rather its oscillatory behavior (the oscillation of the system). This is not to say that the system does not exhibit periodic motion, as the system will oscillate with some period.

Having an equation of motion, we are able to discern different types of oscillatory behavior such as forced, damped and coupled oscillators. These are all cases of oscillation being a 'special case' of periodic motion, as they contain elements of periodic motion (sin, cos, etc)

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, periodic motion from the physical point of view is quite general in the sense that any type of motion that repeats itself after some period of time would be term as periodic.

Where in the case of oscillation, the time period of the periodic motion is quite large, like the motion of the pendulum upto a scale of about seconds and above.

Which I find the periods having small periods concerning to vibrations.

In representing with a graph, the periodic motion would be repeating curves at some constant intervals, the intervals being time.

The curves which are comparable to our senses would be called oscillation and with very high frequency would be called vibration, where both are periodic motions in general.

Comment: *"Where in the case of oscillation, the time period of the periodic motion is quite large, like the motion of the pendulum upto a scale of about seconds and above. Which I find the periods having small periods concerning to vibrations."* ?? Well... I can tell you that electrical engineers use *oscillators* to generate signals of quite high frequencies; for example around 200 GHz corresponding to a time period of 0.000000000005 seconds. Meanwhile, vibrations are also just oscillations, but as far as I know mainly a term for mechanics (will have to look that up for certainty).